# Angular 2 - understanding bidings and pipes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to understand how Angular 2 works. I'm currently reading the pipes documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html and there is the following example:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-birthday',
  template: `
    <p>The hero's birthday is {{ birthday | date:format }}</p>
    <button (click)="toggleFormat()">Toggle Format</button>
  `
})
export class HeroBirthday {
  birthday = new Date(1988,3,15); // April 15, 1988

  toggle = true; // start with true == shortDate

  get format() { return this.toggle ? 'shortDate' : 'fullDate'}

  toggleFormat() { this.toggle = !this.toggle; }
}
```

What puzzles me is why is the `birthday` updated when user clicks on the button?
So... when you click the button , the `toggleFormat()` function is called, which changes `this.toggle` variable. Is there "something" that checks if `this.toggle` is changed and therefore `format` is changed which updates `birthday` ?

Can someone explain how is this working?

Thanks

Comment: What about Victor Savkin's article about [change detection](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eric mentioned in his comment, [Savkin's blog post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2) reveals that every component gets an associated change detector that checks all of the bindings in that component when "change detection" runs.  For a stateless pipe, the bindings are the input data (`birthday`) and the 
parameters (`format`).

Angular uses [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/) to monkey patch / intercept every browser async event.
After every browser event Angular calls its change detection algorithm.

So, you click the button, `toggleFormat()` runs, then change detection runs.  Since the result of `format()` is different every time, this is a "change", hence the pipe is executed/re-evaluated every time.  The DOM is updated by Angular.  At this point change detection is done. The browser then detects/notices the DOM change and updates what you see on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The click handler is triggered but its inside the Angular zone. So after `toggleFormat()` gets called Angular will call it's "digest".

Angular will walk the component tree and where needed take the controller data, apply it to the template and inject the newly generated Html in the page. This is done in the most optimal way possible.

So what you are seeing is normal Angular behaviour, it has not necessarily a relation to the fact that a pipe is being used.If you would print the value of format in the HTML, you would see the same result:

```
{{format}}
```